# How to get link text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get link text using jQuery?

My link is:

```
<a href="htp://www.google.com" id="id1">google site</a>
```

I need to get "google site" using jQuery.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is the text shown to the user in UI not the name. To get that you use a jQuery's text method.

Use the `.text()` method as

```
$('a').text();
```

Even you can use a variable to get the value to, for example:

```
var hyperLinkText = $('a').text(); // get the name
$('element').html(hyperLinkText); // write it somewhere
```

Answer (score 8):

If you means the `href` value of your anchor, then you can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**:

```
var href = $('#id1').attr('href');
```

or **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**:

```
var href = $('#id1').prop('href');
```

If you want to get the text inside anchor, you can use **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**:

```
var text = $('#id1').text();
```

Comment: I think he want "google site" (the text) which is innerHTML (in JS if i don't remember wrong) not the url

Comment: There must be a line between `.attr` and `.prop`

Answer (score 2):

you can try with this:

```
var linkText=$('#id1').text();
```